# In Lightswitch, how do I make a calculated field/property in an Entity/Table based on data in a record from a separate table?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I currently have a formula in c# for a calculated property in a Lightswitch  Entity/Table (HouseIncome).

```
result = NumberInHouseHold >= 1
? (AnnualHouseHoldIncome / (7880 + (NumberInHouseHold * 4180)))
: 0;
```

The NumberInhousehold has a data type of Decimal. The AnnualHouseHoldIncome is a data type of Money. The two numbers are variables which are changed each year. The PFPLevel is a calculated property with a Percent data type.  For each record in this Table there is also a EmploymentDate property with a Date data type.

This calculation works great for 2017 but in 2018, and subsequent years, I would have to recode the calculated field with the new guidelines and information displayed in the PFPLevel field would no longer be accurate for 2017.

I would like to make the PFPLevel calculation based on data entered in a record of the HouseIncome table and the variables drawn from the FPLGuidlines table according to the Employment date. So, if a person in 2017 had a record with an employment date of 6/17/2017, that record would have the PFPlevel calculated on with NumberInHousehold, AnnualHouseHoldIncome, and Guidelines drawn from 2017 record.

In the FPLGuidelines table there would be four fields; Id, YearID, BaseIncome, PerIndividulalAmount which would have a new record each year. I am not sure what data types I would need for each of these properties/fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the following type of entity data types:

[image: example entity fields]

Alongside the following type of approach to your calculated property:

```
partial void PFPLevel_Compute(ref decimal result)
{
    if (EmploymentDate.HasValue)
    {
        var hiy = EmploymentDate.Value.Date.Year;
        var gl = DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.FPLGuidelines.Where(e => e.Year == hiy).Execute().FirstOrDefault();
        if (gl != null)
        {
            result = NumberInHouseHold >= 1
            ? (AnnualHouseHoldIncome / (gl.BaseIncome + (NumberInHouseHold * gl.PerIndividualAmount)))
            : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The above example is based on your HouseIncome.EmploymentDate property being a nullable DateTime.

Comment: Crhis.  Your solution looks close but I am getting an error:                                                                                                             .**Severity Code Description Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ApplicationData' does not contain a definition for 'FPLGuidlines' and no extension method 'FPLGuidlines' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 23 Active**

Comment: Chris,

Now, the only problem I am encountering is in the following var line.
var hiy = EmploymentDate.Date.Year;
Where Date is underlined in red and the following message is displayed.

**'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: If your data source is named something other than ApplicationData, you'll need to change the DataWorkspace.ApplicationData to reflect your data source bame e.g. DataWorkspace.YourDataSourceName.  As regards the Date error, I'd based my example on the HouseIncome.EmploymentDate property being non-nullable.  I'll update my example to demonstrate the approach for a nullable DateTime.

Comment: @Mark I've updated my example to reflect your HouseIncome.EmploymentDate property being a nullable DateTime and have corrected the FPLGuid**e**lines typo.

Comment: @Mark I'm glad it did the trick and please can you mark it as an accepted answer by clicking the tick

Comment: In a bind here. With this solution I get an error when I try to add a new record in the parent table.                                                                                " An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"

Additional information: Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147481/discussion-between-mark-and-chris-cook).